# CSS reduce inline font-size that is set in px

Tags: jquery, css, media-queries, font-size

following problem: I have a site with different font sizes set in px with inline styles.

Is there any possibility to adjust the font-size on resize (for example in a media query) to lets say fontsize*0.6

So if there is set a style="font-size: 24px" and one with style="font-size:60px" I can multiply the values by 0.6 to reduce the font sizes on mobile devices?

Could be a jQuery or CSS solution.

Thanks ins advance

Comment: Try using `vw` units - it will relate the font size to the width of the viewport

Comment: I think you need to look into using `em` rather than `px` - this article describes how they work. Then in your media queries you could use them. http://www.teachingmultimedia.com/mmp240/HowMuchIsThatEm.html

Comment: If the sizes are all set that way, you could simply access the `.style.fontSize` properties of elements and modify their their values. This should be rather straightforward. Whether this makes sense is a different issue. Have you tested that the pages actually have a problem on mobile devices and that a specific font size reduction really solves it, or even addresses it?

Comment: I know it does not make a lot of sense, however that's how the site was coded :) Thanks for the tip with style.fontSize

Answer (score 0):

Why not to specify fonts for all breakpoints usign [`CSS3 @media Query`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/)?

Here is my solution:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    body {
        font-size: 18px;
    }
}


@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    body {
        font-size: 50px;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is what the OP is asking - "I can multiply the values by 0.6 to reduce the font sizes on mobile devices?" is the question here. And please do not use `!important`